# How to set default path for store PDF

Tags: java, spring-boot, itext

I have to store this pdf file in my "/home/gnanaseelan/Documents/myfile" this location How is?

```
ByteArrayInputStream bis = PDFGenerator.customerPDFReport(myLayout);

  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=mypdf.pdf");
       return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
                .body(new InputStreamResource(bis));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have IOUtils (Apache Commons io) you can do it with

```
IOUtils.copy(byteArrayInputStream, new FileOutputStream("/home/gnanaseelan/Documents/myfile.pdf"));
```

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate the PdfWriter class by passing a string value (representing the path where you need to create a PDF) to its constructor, as shown below.

```
// Creating a PdfWriter 
String path = "C:/itextExamples/fonts.pdf"; 
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(path);
```